# Develop a pedometer as a web app?

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications, pedometer

I wanted to ask if it is possible to develop a pedometer in a web app. I want to get the data from the phone (on iPhone the app is called Health). I don't want to do it over Google Maps with gps because of the battery life and the roaming. I didn't find any clues to this question.

Thank you and best regards

Comment: only if the browser engine has an api that provides access to sensors like that. if not, then there is pretty much absolutely nothing you can do about it.